# Clickhouse seems quite slow

Tags: database, time-series, clickhouse

We are considering moving to ClickHouse as a time-series database for an IoT usage, so we followed best practices for creating a table designed for that, but when running tests, the results seemed to be quite slow on first time the query is run, but then it is quite fast (due to cold caching).

Our table schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS feeds (
    ts UInt64,
    uuid UUID,
    value Decimal(30, 5),

    date Date MATERIALIZED toDate(round(ts/1000)) CODEC(DoubleDelta),
    time DateTime MATERIALIZED toDateTime(round(ts/1000)) CODEC(DoubleDelta)
  ) ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree() PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(date) PRIMARY KEY (uuid, ts) ORDER BY (uuid, ts) SETTINGS index_granularity=4096
```

Then to query, we execute this:

```
 SELECT toStartOfInterval(time, INTERVAL '1 day') AS agreg,
        avg(value) AS value
 FROM feeds
WHERE uuid='391becbb-39fd-4205-aba1-5088c9529d42'
  AND ts > 1629378660000
  AND ts < 1632057060000
GROUP BY agreg
ORDER BY agreg ASC
```

Which represents around a month of data, aggregated daily.

We get this result :

```
┌───────────────agreg─┬──────────────value─┐
│ 2021-08-19 00:00:00 │  43.54795698924731 │
│ 2021-08-20 00:00:00 │  33.68460122699386 │
│ 2021-08-23 00:00:00 │   26.8002874251497 │
│ 2021-08-24 00:00:00 │  45.30143348623853 │
│ 2021-08-25 00:00:00 │  43.78214139344263 │
│ 2021-08-26 00:00:00 │  35.66887477313974 │
│ 2021-08-27 00:00:00 │  87.03632541133456 │
│ 2021-08-28 00:00:00 │  87.00372191011236 │
│ 2021-08-29 00:00:00 │  87.16366666666666 │
│ 2021-08-30 00:00:00 │  87.62234215885947 │
│ 2021-08-31 00:00:00 │  87.62653798256538 │
│ 2021-09-01 00:00:00 │  87.08854251012146 │
│ 2021-09-02 00:00:00 │ 44.809177939646204 │
│ 2021-09-03 00:00:00 │  20.85095168374817 │
│ 2021-09-06 00:00:00 │ 21.086067551266584 │
│ 2021-09-07 00:00:00 │ 20.904265569917744 │
│ 2021-09-08 00:00:00 │ 20.988032407407406 │
│ 2021-09-09 00:00:00 │ 21.070418848167538 │
│ 2021-09-10 00:00:00 │ 20.900507674144038 │
│ 2021-09-14 00:00:00 │  34.17651296829971 │
│ 2021-09-15 00:00:00 │  33.79448634590377 │
│ 2021-09-16 00:00:00 │   33.7209536423841 │
│ 2021-09-17 00:00:00 │   33.5361985472155 │
└─────────────────────┴────────────────────┘

Ok. 23 rows in set. Elapsed: 6.891 sec. Processed: 0 rows, 0.0B (0 rows/s, 0.0B/s)
```

7s seems quite slow for such a simple operation.

Is our way of doing this wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't use partitioning and primary index.

1. You have 3 columns with the same temporal data. When you query `ts` and `time` your query processes twice more data. **Get rid of `time` and `date` columns!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**
2. Your table is partitioned by the column `date` and your `where` section uses `AND ts > 1629378660000` === partition elimination does not work!!!
   Use `partition by toYYYYMM(toDateTime(intDiv(ts,1000))` !
3. Do not use `round(ts/1000)`, use `intDiv(ts,1000)`
4. You don't use primary key index. Query Optimizer is stupid, use `GROUP BY uuid, agreg ORDER BY uuid, agreg ASC`
   +try `set optimize_aggregation_in_order=1` Make `agreg` a derivative from `ts`.

`(uuid, agreg (ts) )` pair matches table's `ORDER BY`

5. Yes, CH still will be slower than other timeseries databases, because CH is not designed for such queries.

Comment: Thanks for the tips ! I modified the DB to be based only on timestamp and it is way faster. However, I have to kinda disagree for the part where you say that CH is slower than other timeseries. I tried some TS databases and clickhouse is faster than them, at least for our use case (timescale, influxdb).

Comment: In general CH is not designed for that. CH uses sparse indexes and unable to process small number of rows. (I have 5 years of using CH and I am CH fanboy). Anyway need to have a deep understanding of timescale to make a proper benchmark. https://blog.timescale.com/blog/what-is-clickhouse-how-does-it-compare-to-postgresql-and-timescaledb-and-how-does-it-perform-for-time-series-data/

Comment: how @GuillaumeCaruso- how fast did it get? also, what are your machine specs?